# How to diff VIM tmp file with extant file

Tags: vim

I just opened a long code file in VIM and got the message that a temporary swap file for the file already exists. Both the temporary swap file and the extant file have identical timestamps. I would like to `diff` them, but the temporary swap file is binary. Can VIM show to me the differences between the two files?

Note that I tried to open the temporary swap file with the "Recover" option in VIM and then just `vimdiff` it with the extant file. However, that gave to me the message "Recovery completed. Buffer contents equals file contents" which is nice to know, but I would still like to know how to `diff` the files *beforehand* in the event that they don't match. In that case, is it still viable to open the temporary swap file in VIM and then `vimdiff` it with the extant file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [recover.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3068). It installs a hook that asks you what to do when a swap file has been detected, and offers to show a diff.